# visual studio code not running code cause of ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ofstream

I have set up my Visual Studio Code and it works fine, but when I want to use `fstream` functions, it doesn't run. Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void createfile();

int main(){
    int choice;
    cout << "Enter 1 to create file" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            createfile();
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void createfile(){
    ofstream file ("file.txt");
    file.close();
}
```

The terminal says:

```
PS D:\vs code cpp> cd "d:\vs code cpp\" ; if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
```

And then after trying to run, it says:

```
PS D:\vs code cpp>
```

Literally nothing. I even reinstalled Visual Studio Code, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: is `-0` supposed to be `-o`?

Comment: yes I've mistyped it

Comment: So is this exactly what is in your terminal? did you copy and paste it? If you've typed it in you might have accidentally fixed another typo which is the cause of your problem

Comment: I couldn't copy and paste it so I've typed

Comment: I've checked it and it is exactly the same

Comment: Is your code compiling/running? Try making a syntax error and see if an error pops up. If one does, then check runtime by throwing an exception or something.

Comment: No its not even running i added a simple cout at top and it didn't show it

Comment: The code itself is fine. Your terminal output looks like a makefile is being dumped as-is to the terminal instead of being processed by a build system, like `make`/`cmake`.

Comment: What should I do then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed mingw again and it worked.